# 'might be' vs 'might have been'

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

> I called her at six but she didn't talk to me. She **might have been busy**; that is why she didn't talk to me.
>
> I called her at six but she didn't talk to me. She **might be busy**; that is why she didn't talk to me.
>
> I called her at six but she didn't talk to me. I think that she was busy.

Could you please tell me differences between "Might be" and "Might have been"?

Comment: The difference is an idea in the present and in the past: she might be busy (now or on Saturdays). She might have been busy yesterday, last week or whenever. Sentence two is agrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether there is an expectation that she is still busy.

> I called her at six but she didn't talk to me. She **might have been** busy; that is why she didn't talk to me.

but you expect she might not be busy now.

> I called her at six but she didn't talk to me. She **might be** busy; that is why she didn't talk to me.

when you expect she might still be busy.

The second would be more likely if it is now a short time after six.

Otherwise, using simple past tense is the safe choice.

Comment: But when we say "I called her at six but she didn't talk to me. I thought she might have been busy. Why is it considered wrong? I mean we have to say "I called her at six but she didn't talk to me. I thought she "might" or "would" be busy" or "I went to her to borrow a book because I thought she might have it" (so why not "Might have had" here instead of "Might" or "Would"?) Is it because I used "I thought" here? Can I say "I think she might have had it"?

Comment: Additional questions should be added by editing your question.

Comment: That sounds "might be" is the persent tense, but "might" is the past form of "may".
Then what's the different between "may be" and "might be"?

Answer (score 0):

"Called" is past tense, you're describing a past event.  The second sentence explains why the event might have been, so that reason is a condition that also happened in the past, concurrent with the event.

"Might have been" refers to the past, so that's the matching phrase.  "Might be" refers to the present.  Whether she's busy now is irrelevant to whether that was the reason she couldn't talk at a past time.

Comment: “"Might be" refers to the present.” why?
But "might" is the past form of "may".

Comment: @Zhang, the dictionary does list a usage of might as a past form of may, but that is not a common usage, at least today in American English. It isn't even clear to me why the example of that usage given in Websters would be considered past tense. The example describes permission, liberty, probability, or possibility that could apply to any time frame. Common usage of might (other than as a form of politeness), describes possibility, and additional words (often forms of "be"), provide the context of a time frame (might **be** = present, might **have been** = past).